# show automatic number test case

Tags: testcase, testlink

I wanted to know if is there any way of hidding the automatic number that TestLink shows when you create a new Test Case.
In my example, "idERP" is the ID of the project, but the "-1, -2..." is an automatic number that TestLink shows, and I would prefer not to see this numbers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testlink automatic test case numbering is pretty annoying. 
User cannot re-order the test case number.

As far as from my own experiments and exploration of the software, there's no way you can control the test case numbering sequence or toggle even toggle it's visibility using the GUI.

The only way you can control this is to dig into the Testlink's source code and modify the code that handles the test case numbering.

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestLink), identifier of a Test Case is assigned automatically by TestLink, and cannot be changed by users. This ID composes from Test Project prefix and a counter related to the Test Project in which the Test Case is created.

[Testlink v1.9.13 - Stormbringer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/testlink/files/latest/download?source=files)